# How to terminate the docplex code after timelimit

Tags: cplex, docplex

I am using docplex.mp and I am running an Integer optimisation problem that takes about several days.. I need to terminate the program after a certain time limit and obtain a solution for whatever the limit left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timelimit Parameter as can be seen in

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoosettings.py

Comment: For determined time limit, optimal solution cannot be found. How can I achieve the gap in the time limit?